# Interprocess communication between independent Python3 scripts

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Can we use standard multiprocessing.Queue class for communicating between independent Python3 scripts like

```
bash% ./aaa.py &
bash% ./bbb.py &
```

If no, Is there another library like standard multiprocessing module for communicating with independent scripts.

Comment: I chose multiprocessing.managers module, its sample code url is https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the section on ["Listeners and Clients" in the `multiprocessing` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection); unlike the higher level simpler APIs, these APIs allow you to establish connections by address and authenticate the paired process, which allows two Python scripts to cooperate without having a parent/child relationship.

Comment: I know multiprocessing.connection module. Sorry for not explaining enough.  I'm seeking the higher level simpler APIs.

Comment: @shiina: The simpler APIs don't handle named addresses. I'd look at `subprocess` and/or `multiprocessing`'s source code (the high level stuff is all in Python anyway) to get an idea of what they do and the proper way to solve your specific problem.

Comment: But, I didn't know multiprocessing.managers module. Your answer led me to the module. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

It's a self answer. My minimum example is below.

aaa.py

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import queue

queue_a = queue.Queue()
queue_b = queue.Queue()
BaseManager.register('queue_a', callable=lambda: queue_a)
BaseManager.register('queue_b', callable=lambda: queue_b)
m = BaseManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'qwerty')
m.start()

shared_queue_a = m.queue_a()
shared_queue_b = m.queue_b()

shared_queue_a.put("How are you?")
msg = shared_queue_b.get()
print("%s: %s" % (__file__, msg))

m.shutdown()
```

bbb.py

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager


BaseManager.register('queue_a')
BaseManager.register('queue_b')
m = BaseManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'qwerty')
m.connect()

queue_a = m.queue_a()
queue_b = m.queue_b()

msg = queue_a.get()
print("%s: %s" % (__file__, msg))
queue_b.put("I'm fine.")
```

Run these scripts.

```
./aaa.py &; sleep 1; ./bbb.py
```

Prints

```
./bbb.py: How are you?
./aaa.py: I'm fine.
```

Comment: It's a pity you've published the self answer without publishing an explanation. It is not clear what is a BaseManager, how it works, and why are there 2 queues and not one?

Comment: queue_a and queue_b are two different queues. Each queue represents messages coming from either aaa.py or bbb.py. For BaseManager, see the python docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager