# How can I send messages between separate processes in Python?

Tags: python, unix, parallel-processing

I've been struggling researching this for hours, maybe someone here can help.

The situation is that there are two Python 3 processes, A and B. A starts running before B, and can continue to run after B finishes. A can call B to run, ideally an arbitrary number of times.

A must get its info from process B, and then send its decision back to B. A can do some setup and call B to run; it then would wait, receive info from B, make a command, send the command to B, and wait again, unless the command was for B to finish. A runs regardless of whether B has finished.

Pretend the info from B is inaccessible by any means besides having B pass it to A in some way.

I figured out a way to do it writing to disk; The way I've been trying to lessen disk writes is to use mkfifo from the os module, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

I don't see a way to flush what I write with os; I can't get it to work with or without os.fsync.

Does anyone have a general approach for unix-like OS?

Comment: Sockets and pipes are the usual generic approaches for communicating between processes.

Comment: Multiprocessing Manager is easy and effective https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interprocess communication between independent Python3 scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440533/interprocess-communication-between-independent-python3-scripts)

Comment: @Kemp I've seen like 3 different versions of pipes in the standard library. It doesn't seem obvious which to use nor how to use them. I'll assume you mean the pipes module for now and try that

Comment: Why not just use the very simple `multiprocessing Queue` suggested above. It's very simple, you just do `queue.put((thing1, thing2, thing3))` and `queue.get()` at the other end.